# brave browser will not open

Tags: 18.04, browser, brave

The brave browser worked great for me for many months. I have discovered several extensions which I enabled carefully including "The Great Suspender" so keeping tabs open doesn't consume unnecessary resources.

Last week after an update when I click the icon in the lxde menu bar I see no windows opening at all.

It's not opening a blank white window like I saw reported elsewhere, just nothing.

I believe I installed using the most current method, not snap. 1.0.1 recently came out.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i brave
ii  brave-browser    1.0.1  amd64   The web browser from Brave
ii  brave-keyring    1.7      all   Brave Browser keyring and repository files
```

I see it's trying to open but doesn't:

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i brave
grantbow  4732  4160  0 12:42 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
grantbow  4739  4732 28 12:42 ?        00:00:09 /opt/brave.com/brave/brave
grantbow  4743  4739  0 12:42 ?        00:00:00 /opt/brave.com/brave/brave --type=zygote
grantbow  4747  4743  0 12:42 ?        00:00:00 /opt/brave.com/brave/brave --type=zygote
grantbow  4766  4739  4 12:42 ?        00:00:01 /opt/brave.com/brave/brave --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle=1515
8583491962856952,6341817588596150380,131072 --enable-features=NewExtensionUpdaterService,PasswordImport,SimplifyHttpsIn
dicator,WebUIDarkMode --disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess,AutofillServerCommunication,LookalikeUrlNavigationSug
gestionsUI,NotificationTriggers,SmsReceiver,SyncUSSBookmarks,UnifiedConsent --gpu-preferences=KAAAAAAAAAAgAAAgAAAAAAAAY
AABAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAA --service-request-channel-token=5765932197625944813
```

...

I looked in ~/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default but didn't find anything I recognized as relevant.

I saw discussions about enabling a kernel namespace configuration like this [github thread](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/3420) but those reports do not seem current and I am not sure a change of that type would have happened recently though it's possible.

My first concern was to backup my settings. I am not sure how to start without extensions. I saw a [brave support template](https://community.brave.com/t/support-templates-reference/36549) on the brave site but not details on how to check my settings or a process by which to narrow down the causes. Without at least a workaround to get an open window I am limited in exploring the settings very well.

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: perhaps because brave is based on chromium some of the same steps should be followed to narrow down a problem.

Comment: aha, `$ /opt/brave.com/brave.brave` will get a window open but it's not using my profile or any of the data I want to find a way to reuse.

Comment: debug logs are described https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en

Comment: this seems to help get closer to the problem! From a terminal `$ /opt/brave.com/brave/brave --type=zygote --enable-logging=stderr --v=1` yields infinite messages like `[24784:24784:0100/000000.261653:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(240)] Error reading message from browser: Socket operation on non-socket (88)`

Comment: a google for "debugging google chrome zygote" lead me to https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_debugging.md

Comment: after reading a link from https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/290 this did not solve the issue for me: `sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Brave completely

```
sudo apt remove brave

rm -r ~/.config/BraveSoftware
```

Install Brave

```
sudo snap install brave
```

If you don't have *Snap* activated [read here](https://snapcraft.io/install/brave/ubuntu)

Comment: snap packages of brave are deprecated. https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux

Comment: Not exactly check the release date, it's the last stable release. It may not be updated that frequently but it is updated.

Comment: i'm using the most supported ubuntu version installed like other debian/ubuntu packages. I found the last snaps I tried to be not fully integrated with desktop environments yet.

Comment: your answer also doesn't help me recover the profile data which is important.